# Text holes on polygon cylinder - boolean operation Maya 2010

Tags: maya, boolean-operations

I have been trying to make letter holes on a polygon cylinder. I have made the letter through Text option. I set the height a bit bigger than the height of the cylinder.

Then, using the Boolean Operation I tried to remove the letter from the cylinder, in order to make the hole. Both objects, cylinder and letter disappeared, although the letter should only be disappeared.

This video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc50WFjyynQ  shows what I am trying to do, but instead of removing the object, I am trying to remove the 3D Text(which I made with Bevel option).

Any advice will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use a trial version of Rhino, and you'll get a model as you expect with the booleans.

On the other hand, using booleans for modeling is not a good practice, you can still use Maya and make either `bump maps` or `displacement maps`

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mdR2imNeZI) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bqS-z0-GJo)

Answer (score 1):

Maya boolean operations are very bad.

Try it with nurbs and "project curve on surface"... After working with nurbs you can convert the object to a polygon object and edit it further.

Or you can attend the beta of the [Boole plug-in from ticket01](http://www.ticket01.com/beta/index.php)